# swift argument labels and keywords

Tags: swift

I am trying to learn Swift and came across the argument labels and an online example as follows:

```
func setAge(for person: String, to value: Int) {
    print("\(person) is now \(value)")
}
```

This can be then called as:

```
setAge(for: "Paul", to: 40)
```

My question is that isn't `for` a Swift keyword? I am wondering whether this use of `for` has some hidden meaning that I am missing or just that these keywords can also be used as argument labels?

Comment: A *swiftier* signature is`func setAge(_ age: Int, for person: String) {` -> `setAge(40, for: "Paul")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> or just that these keywords can also be used as argument labels?

Exactly. This is introduced in [SE-0001 Allow (most) keywords as argument labels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0001-keywords-as-argument-labels.md). The motivation is that:

> Sometimes, the most natural label for an argument coincides with a language keyword, such as `in`, `repeat`, or `defer`. Such keywords should be allowed as argument labels, allowing better expression of these interfaces.

Though in SE-0001 it is said that `inout`, `var` and `let` are not allowed to be argument labels (back then they are used to describe the mutability of the parameter). This restriction was later relaxed. Now, only `inout` is not allowed as an argument label, and you get a warning if you use `var` or `let` as an argument label.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this keyword can also be used as argument label.
Swift gives you flexibility to use any keyword except inout as argument label as it increases readability.